# Linux AMIs to get started on Amazon EC2 with Java application server

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, linux

I'm trying to set up my first Amazon EC2 instance and having trouble selecting the right AMI given the huge amount of choice available.

Requirements:

- Intended to run one (smallish) web
  site with a Java based application
  server
- Run the latest Java 1.6 server version
- Serve some static files efficiently e.g. with Apache
- As simple to administer as possible - I'm a primarily a
  developer, not a sysadmin!
- 32 bit instance to start with, but have the option to move to 64 bit as
  needed

What Linux version / AMI would you recommend to meet these requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for one of the public AMIs with a recent version of Ubuntu.  The Amazon standard AMIs can be useful, but they are all on really old releases such as Fedora 8 due to the kernel that they use, so you might have problems installing recent versions of packages that you need.

I see there are a few public AMIs with Ubuntu Karmic - you should be good with a 32-bit version of that running on an m1.small type instance.

Comment: Update; Amazon just introduced User Managed Kernels (http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?categoryID=174&externalID=3967) to let you specify your own kernel.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using this AMI: ami-2d4aa444 (US East)